# How to compare a java.util.date with oracle's SYSDATE in query using jdbctemplate query

Tags: java, sql, oracle, spring-jdbc

I have a query

```
select case when datefield >sysdate then 0 else columnvalue
```

How to give value for `datefield` in similar format as `sysdate` has in Oracle? I am using jdbc template to query from java code. Currently the `datefield` is in `yyyy-MM-dd` format.

Note: datefield is not a column in database.It is a parameter passed from java

Comment: not sure if java messes something up, but how about SELECT CASE WHEN TO_DATE(datefield, 'yyyy-mm-dd') > SYSDATE THEN 0 ELSE columnvalue

Comment: If `datefield` is already of type `DATE`, there is nothing to do. A date does not have a "format". Strings have formats. And yes, comparing dates with "day-precision" is done by using `trunc()` on *both* (!) sides.

Comment: Is `datefield` a column in a database table?

Comment: date field is not a column in database.It is a value supplied as input from java

Comment: Use a placeholder `?` and pass an instance of `java.time.LocalDateTime` or `java.sql.Timestamp` to the `PreparedStatement`

Comment: @UniversE ..These are not working.

Comment: Oracle's `SYSDATE` is a built-in database function that returns a value whose [Oracle] data-type is DATE. This data-type contains both a date and a time. What is the [java] data-type of `datefield`? The Oracle documentation - _JDBC Developer's Guide_ - contains mappings between java classes and database types.

Comment: @Abra datatype of datefield is java.util.date

Answer (score 0):

Did you try @a_horse_with_no_name's suggestion of using `java.sql.PreparedStatement`?
Alternatively, you could use *JDBC Escape Syntax*. The code would be something like the following...

```
java.sql.Connection conn = // However you obtain it.
String sql = "select case when {d '2019-06-27'} > trunc(sysdate) then 0 else columnvalue";
java.sql.PreparedStatement ps = conn.prepareStatement(sql);
java.sql.ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

Note that you can manipulate the `sql` string in the above code the way you manipulate any string. For example you can use method `String.format()` to replace the hard-coded date (2019-06-27) with an instance of `java.util.Date`.